# Bash: split by comma with special characters

Tags: bash

I have a list that is comma delimited like so...

```
 00:00:00:00:00:00,Bob's Laptop,11111111111111111
 00:00:00:00:00:00,Mom & Dad's Computer,22222222222222222
 00:00:00:00:00:00,Kitchen,33333333333333333
```

I'm trying to loop over these lines and populate variables with the 3 columns in each row.  My script works when the data has no spaces, ampersands, or apostrophes. When it does have those then it doesn't work right.  Here is my script:

```
 for line in $(cat list) 
 do 
    arr=(`echo $line | tr "," "\n"`)
    echo "Field1: ${arr[0]}"    
    echo "Field2: ${arr[1]}"
    echo "Field3: ${arr[2]}"
 done
```

If one of you bash gurus can point out how I can get this script to work with my list I would greatly appreciate it!

EV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while IFS=, read field1 field2 field3
do
  echo $field1
  echo $field2
  echo $field3
done < list
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you use awk?

```
awk -F',' '{print "Field1: " $1 "\nField2: " $2 "\nField3: " $3}'
```

Answer (score 3):

[Do not read lines with a for loop.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) Use `read` instead

```
while IFS=, read -r -a line;
do 
    printf "%s\n" "${line[0]}" "${line[1]}" "${line[2]}";
done < list
```

Or, using array slicing

```
while IFS=, read -r -a line;
do 
    printf "%s\n" "${line[@]:0:3}"; 
done < list
```